# Using the Azure API, how do I list and add virtual directories to a website?

Tags: c#, winforms, azure

I am trying to add a Virtual Directory to an Azure Web Site from a WinForms Application using the Azure API.  I can enumerate the WebSites on in my webspace, but I cannot find a method that allows me access to the Virtual Directories in the WebSite.

Here is my code:

```
        string certPath = Properties.Settings.Default.AzureCertificatePath;
        string certPassword = Properties.Settings.Default.AzureCertificatePassword;
        string subscriptionId = Properties.Settings.Default.AzureSubscriptionId;
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, certPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        var cred = new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, cert);

        using (var client = new WebSiteManagementClient(cred))
        {
            var spaces = client.WebSpaces.List();
            foreach (var space in spaces)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Space: {0}", space.Name);

                var sites = client.WebSpaces.ListWebSites(space.Name, new WebSiteListParameters {PropertiesToInclude = { "Name" } }); ***// Where do I find out what properties can be included in this array?***
                foreach (var site in sites)
                {
                    ***// What goes here to show the virtual directories in this specific website??????***
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: More for those coming later than the OP: `PropertiesToInclude` causes the library to add `propertiesToInclude` to the queryString in the API URL, and that query string **does nothing** - at all. As of April 2016, the .NET library is still heavily outdated and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the Azure web services API does not offer access to the virtual directories/applications on a web app, although the underlying REST API's that it uses does.

Luckily, the management API is open source (I wanted to get the v3.0.0.0 of the website management API, matching what I had NuGet'd, which I found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/commits/master?page=79) so with a little perseverance and messing about with .targets files and NuGet references, you can get the source code of the **WebSiteManagement** project into your solution instead of the referenced DLL that you likely downloaded from NuGet.

From there, if you go into your `client.WebSites.GetConfiguration` method, stick a breakpoint in and capture the HTTP response returned - you'll see that in the JSON the `VirtualApplications` on your website are indeed there.

From there, you can edit your copy of the source code to expose those object structures out, much the same way that other object structures are mapped out of the JSON (e.g. `HandlerMappings`).

Likewise for updating them, you need to add the VirtualApplications (in the ewact same format) into the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.Models.WebSiteUpdateConfigurationParameters`, and pass that into `client.WebSites.UpdateConfiguration` (which you will also need to amend to map your VirtualApplications object structure back into JSON in the same format).

Works great for me doing it this way.

**Note/Disclaimer:** The GitHub site documentation does mention that much of the source code was autogenerated, and that you shouldn't really go editing that code, instead raise an issue on the project about getting it sorted. I didn't have the time to do this and needed an immediate way of getting it working with my local copy of the code only, so my solution does, as you'll note when you look a the source, involve adding to that auto-gen'd code. It works great, but I should in good conscience point you to the project owner's warnings about tinkering with the auto-gen'd code.