# How to create Websites and virtual directories on Azure using Windows Azure Management Libraries?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-management-api

I have created a web app on Windows Azure using Windows Azure Management Libraries. Below is the code

```
var client = new WebSiteManagementClient(cred);

var parameters = new WebSiteCreateParameters
{
    Name = SiteName,
    SiteMode = WebSiteMode.Limited,
    ComputeMode = WebSiteComputeMode.Shared,
    WebSpaceName = WebSpaceName
};

parameters.HostNames.Add(
    string.Format("{0}.azurewebsites.net", SiteName)
);

var result = client.WebSites.Create(WebSpaceName, parameters);
```

Now I want to create sub-directories/virtual directory inside this web app. Please guide me.

Comment: It looks like you are using an older version of the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries`. I.e. you might be using 1.0.0 given the properties you are setting. Are you willing to upgrade?

Comment: I have provided an answer to this here, on this closely-related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000178/using-the-azure-api-how-do-i-list-and-add-virtual-directories-to-a-website/33996247#33996247